# jQuery-Handsontable and Twitter Bootstrap responsive.css Copy/Paste issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, copy-paste, responsive-design

I'm having an issue using jQuery-Handsontable with Twitter Bootstrap.

I can't use jQuery-Handsontable copy-paste functionality with Twitter Bootstrap Responsive style sheet.

If i delete the bootstrap-responsive.css it's working like charm! But i need to use twitter bootstrap responsive css. If i can't combine them together at least i wanna know why i'm having this issue.

Here is the example link(http://jsfiddle.net/tevfik/mJVpA/); Try to remove bootstrap-responsive.css from "Manage Resources". You'll see copy/paste will work on table.

I need to solve this problem.

Other Links;
http://warpech.github.com/jquery-handsontable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Firebug showed that there was a conflict for ".hidden" class in CSS. I have fixed Handsontable to use name spaced class name (now it is called ".htHidden".

Make sure you upgrade to the current version and it will be fine.